not getting results from pinecone database
here is the code I used insert into Pinecone DB, data was inserted successfully but when querying the DB the results were empty as the picture below
index_name="medical-chatbot"
index = pc.Index(index_name)  
for i, t in zip(range(len(text_chunks)), text_chunks):
   query_result = embedings.embed_query(t.page_content)
   index.upsert(
   vectors=[
        {
            "id": str(i),  # Convert i to a string
            "values": query_result, 
            "metadata": {"text":str(text_chunks[i].page_content)} # meta data as dic
        }
    ],
    namespace="real" 
)

index.describe_index_stats() 


query_text = "what is insomnia"
query_vector = embedings.embed_query(query_text)


# Query the index
query_result = index.query(query_vector, top_k=5, include_metadata=True, filter={"score__gt": 0.5}, namespace="real")
query_result


result of the query
